# Cursors for data selection in matplotlib

Tags: user-interface, matplotlib, user-input

I am trying to get user input from matplotlib XY plot. The plot contains multiple datasets and I need get from user selection of which dataset to use and the range. I need this to fit model to right dataset and range.
Therefore I need two indicators, which would be "attached" to specific dataset, per user choosing. I need to get from them both the dataset info and the range info.
Somehow in line with what commercial plotting packages (Igor Pro, Kaleidagraph, Sigmaplot...) provide as "cursors" and similarly named widgets for control of their fitting interface, which is what I am trying to reproduce.

I have checked various examples with rangeselector and other methods I was able to Google on the web, but none I was able to find seems to be able to provide what I need.

Would anyone have any pointers to where to look or what to start with, please?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at this example: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/ginput_manual_clabel.html
The interesting functions are ginput, waitforbuttonpress.